# How can I find a NativeScript TextField with Appium on Android?

Tags: appium, nativescript

I'm trying to setup automated e2e tests using nativescript-dev-appium. I can't figure out how to locate a TextField when running a NativeScript app through Appium on Android. I'm using tns-core-modules v5.2.1 and nativescript-angular 7.0.2.

The only NativeScript element property I can find that seems to be for automation tests to find elements is `automationText`. When I set `automationText` on iOS, I can find a text field by using the Appium driver's `driver.findElementByAutomationId` or `driver.findElementByAutomationText`. However, when on Android, neither of those methods return the right element. `findElementByAutomationId` doesn't work at all (I think automation IDs may be iOS-specific), and `findElementByAutomationText` is returning a label next to my TextField and not the TextField itself.

My actual view has quite a few TextFields, but here's the basic idea:

```html
<StackLayout>
  <Label text="Name"></Label>
  <TextField automationText="Name" ...></TextField>
</StackLayout>
```

Then, in my e2e test, I want to do this

```js
const nameInput = await driver.findElementByAutomationText("Name") // Returns the Label and not the TextField
```

Since `findElementByAutomationText` seems to be searching elements by Text and not by AutomationText on Android, what is the most reliable way I could find my TextField when running my tests? Preferably, I'd like a cross-platform solution so I don't have to use different find strategies on iOS and Android.

Comment: I should also note that, when I inspect my app in the Appium inspector, the TextField does not have a content-desc nor any property that is set to "Name".

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you ask the developer to set id locator for the given component and use below snippet.

```
await driver.findElementById("#name");
```

I see your component doesn't have locator which is a reliable also....

Comment: Since this is NativeScript, that selector is not available. `findElementById` is not a function on the Appium Driver variant found in nativescript-dev-appium.